# Using readability parser API to fetch image url from web page

Tags: php, parsing, get

Here I found readability which parse the data from web page and give information of interest.
But I could not understand how to use it.

https://www.readability.com/developers/api/parser

Request: GET /api/content/v1/parser?url=http://blog.readability.com/2011/02/step-up-be-heard-readability-ideas/&token=1b830931777ac7c2ac954e9f0d67df437175e66e

It gives json response.

I am working on PHP, how to make above request for particular url like http://google.com?

UPDATE1:

```
<?php
define('TOKEN', "1b830931777ac7c2ac954e9f0d67df437175e66e");
define('API_URL', "https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url=%s&token=%s");

function get_image($url) {

    // sanitize it so we don't break our api url
    $encodedUrl = urlencode($url);
    //$TOKEN = '1b830931777ac7c2ac954e9f0d67df437175e66e';

    //Also tried with $API_URL = 'http://blog.readability.com/2011/02/step-up-be-heard-readability-ideas'; with no luck

    // build our url
    $url = sprintf(API_URL, $encodedUrl, TOKEN); //Also tried with $TOKEN

    // call the api
    $response = file_get_contents($url);

    if( $response ) {
        return false;
    }

    $json = json_decode($response);

    if(!isset($json['lead_image_url'])) {
        return false;
    }

    return $json['lead_image_url'];
}

echo get_image('http://nextbigwhat.com/');

?>
```

Any issue with code? gives error - >

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnextbigwhat.com&amp;token=1b830931777ac7c2ac954e9f0d67df437175e66e): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN in F:\wamp\www\inviteold\test2.php on line 14
```

Comment: The documentation you linked to is pretty clear. Specifically, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Chris: Suppose I have url `http://www.nextbigwhat.com/` and want to parse data using this API then how can I make request inside PHP code??

Comment: What have you tried? We can only help you with *specific problems*, working from code that you have written.

Comment: Regarding the update, you clearly have some problems with your PHP installation, the code is OK.

Comment: @s3v3n: no php installation is ok. I am already using `file_get_content($url)` successfully on my other page

Comment: Even with https urls? It is possible that your php installation doesn't have openssl

Comment: Yes with both http and https

Comment: `https://ca-mg5.mail.yahoo.com/neo/launch?nmig=yes#mail` this short of url also works fine with my another page

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
define('TOKEN', "your_token_here");
define('API_URL', "https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url=%s&token=%s");

function get_image($url) {

    // sanitize it so we don't break our api url
    $encodedUrl = urlencode($url);

    // build our url
    $url = sprintf(API_URL, $encodedUrl, $token);

    // call the api
    $response = file_get_contents($url);

    if( $response ) {
        return false;
    }

    $json = json_decode($response);

    if(!isset($json['lead_image_url'])) {
        return false;
    }

    return $json['lead_image_url'];
}
```

The code is not tested so you might need to adjust it.